# AutoHotKey -Windows Copy an image from a website to clipboard

Tags: html, web-scraping, autohotkey

I am trying to see if there is some way I can copy an image from a website into clipboard so I can save it in paint. or just plain save the image into paint. I can got to the website and select the element by the id. but after I have the id selected I am lost on how to copy it over to clipboard or to save it. I am trying not having to auto hot key a right mouse click and scroll down to save image. I am prepared to if needed but want to make sure there are no other options. Is there another option besides that ?

```
myImage := img.document
myImage.getElementById("image")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript [clipboardData object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms535220(v=vs.85).aspx) ([see also](http://codebits.glennjones.net/copypaste/copydata.htm)) only works if the user have triggered a copy/paste event. Example: If something was copied from the website to clipboard, the copied content can be edited.

**On AutoHotKey you can do it like this:**

1- Use `RegExMatch()` to get the image(s) URL(s) from the HTML code.

2- Use `UrlDownloadToFile, URL, Filename` to save the image(s) on file(s).

Example of picking up the first PNG image of a website:

```
FileDelete, source.html ;clear previous tests (if any)
UrlDownloadToFile, http://www.freestock.tk, source.html ;copy the html code to your PC
Recheck:
if FileExist("source.html") ;check if the html code was downloaded already
{
FileRead, sourcevar, source.html ;pass the html code into a variable
Position := RegExMatch(sourcevar, "is)images/(.*?).png", imagename) ; search for a image pattern 
picurl:= "http://www.freestock.tk/images/" imagename1 ".png" ; build the complete pic url 
picname:= imagename1 ".png" ; build the complete pic name
UrlDownloadToFile, %picurl%, %picname% ; save the picture into a file
}
else
{
Sleep, 5000
goto, Recheck   
}
return
```

*ps: code tested and working.*

Comment: Will this work on a password protected secured site ? I should of mentioned that my mistake.

Comment: I haven't tested on any website with password or httpS. On the AutoHotKey docs they have an example where they use `UrlDownloadToFile, URL, Filename` on ftp (wich requires user/pasword): `UrlDownloadToFile, ftp://user:pass@example.com:21/home/My File.zip, C:\My Folder\My File.zip` [LINK](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/URLDownloadToFile.htm)

Comment: it won't copy the image to the clipboard thought, right? so doesn't fully answer the question